# Get image size from handler

Tags: php, image, editor, size

I'm creating an image editor in JS/PHP, but now I'm having trouble. First of all, I load the image from the database (load a blob with imagecreatefromstring). Then I apply a list of actions to this image. But how can I get the image size from this image handler I have then? Without writing it to a file or use a stream object. How??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you mean the image dimensions:

```
$width  = imagesx($imgHandle);
$height = imagesy($imgHandle);
```

See [`imagesx()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and [`imagesy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php).

If you mean filesize, that's not possible without converting the GD resource to some image format (GIF, PNG, JPEG) because the format determines the image size in bytes.

Comment: presumably he has done this in order to pass it to the client (?)

Comment: Thnx, this is what I was looking for :).

Comment: I mean that in order to pass the image to the client for manipulation, he probably emitted a header and made a call such as `imagepng()` or `imagejpeg()`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can since php gd image object is a generic object, without considerations on the compression that will be used for storage (png/jpg/bmp ...)